# Scraping the data from ServiceDesk requests using requests

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I work as Level 3 support for an app and I mainly put requests from ManageEngine ServiceDesk to Jira and is kinda boring. So I thought I can make a web scraper in Python using requests library that can take information about the issue from `ServiceDesk(title,description,prirority,etc)` and put it in Jira. I've made a script that connects to Jira and submits a ticket but I can't figure out how to login to ServiceDesk... I try to login using username, password and domain but still not working, I use the user-agent as the header. When I run the script to show me content it shows the login page content. I don't know if someone from outside can help but it's worth trying.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = {
'user-agent': 'xxxx'}
cookies = {
'sdpcsrfcookie': 'xxxx',}
data = {
    'j_username': 'xxxx',
    'j_password': 'xxxx',
    'domain': x,
    'DOMAIN_NAME': 'xxxx',
    'LocalAuthWithDomain': 'xxxx',
    'logonDomainName': 'xxxx',
    'AUTHRULE_NAME': 'xxxx'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
   url = "https://sv.info"
   r = s.get(url, headers=headers)
   print(r.cookies)
   cookies['session'] = cookie_string = "; ".join([str(x)+"="+str(y) for x,y in cookies.items()])
   r = s.post(url,headers=headers,data= data, cookies=cookies)
   print(r.content)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should send the `data` as a JSON string, and add a header to your request using `s.headers.update(headers)` all in all your code should look like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = {
'user-agent': 'xxxx'}
cookies = {
'sdpcsrfcookie': 'xxxx',}
data = {
    'j_username': 'xxxx',
    'j_password': 'xxxx',
    'domain': x,
    'DOMAIN_NAME': 'xxxx',
    'LocalAuthWithDomain': 'xxxx',
    'logonDomainName': 'xxxx',
    'AUTHRULE_NAME': 'xxxx'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    url = "https://sv.info"
    s.headers.update(headers)
    r = s.get(url)
    print(r.cookies)
    cookies['session'] = cookie_string = "; ".join([str(x)+"="+str(y) for x,y in cookies.items()])
    r = s.post(url, json=data, cookies=cookies)
    print(r.content)
```